# External site redirects www to non-www. This causes a conflict inside our network. How bad is my idea for a fix?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2016, internal-dns

Our network has a domain named after our business: `business.com`. Our new website has just been finished and is live, but the developer has chosen to redirect all www traffic to the non-www URL; so `www.business.com` 301 redirects to `business.com`.

Internally our domain controller/DNS server has an entry for `www.business.com` pointing to the external site's IP, rather than letting it forward on the request to the external DNS network, but we don't have `business.com` pointed to that IP. This means that when you visit the site from inside the network you have to include the `www.` and then it redirects you to the other URL, which resolves internally to a non-existent site.

The question then is two-fold:

1. Would creating an A record for `business.com` to the external IP cause issue with machines attempting to authenticate to the domain? (Note that this wouldn't be a wildcard.)
2. Is there some other kind of record or setup I could have, using just DNS or also IIS, to take HTTP/S traffic from inside the network that's bound for `business.com` and route it out to the web?

Answer (score 0):

1: no. Machines authenticating refers to dedicated records. I would create a CNAME referring to the main record (the www one in your case)

2: maybe, but 1 is much easier and (almost) granted to work